# How to correct csv file mixed types if using pyarrow write dataset to parquet?

Tags: python, file, types, format, pyarrow

I am currently using pyarrow to read a bunch of .csv files from a directory into a dataset like so:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

# create dataset from csv files
dataset = ds.dataset(input_pat,
                         format="csv",
                         exclude_invalid_files = True)
```

After creating the dataset I write it to parquet format like so:

```
ds.write_dataset(dataset, 
                 format = "parquet", 
                 base_dir = output_path,
                 basename_template = "name_data" +'_{i}.parquet',
                 existing_data_behavior = "overwrite_or_ignore")
```

Now I use this for two datasets, where for the first dataset it works perfectly well. For the second dataset I am receiving an error:

```
ArrowInvalid: In CSV column #14: Row #111060: CSV conversion error to null: invalid value '0'
```

As I understand PyArrow does not like it if there are integer values ("0") in my string columns. Now, if this is the only violation, is there a way for me to explicitly correct it when creating the dataset ? For example, I would like to replace "0" with "unknown" at reading time.

This would be very nice as I do not want to correct the mistakes in an additional function beforehand. The data can be found [here](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page). For the yellow taxis there are no problems. The problem occurs when reading csv files for the green taxis.

If I define the schema, will the error be solved? Will it understand, that it should treat "0" as a string?

Comment: What does `ds` stands for?

Comment: My bad, it stands for pyarrow.dataset. See my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My undrestanding is that in most files, the 14th column (`ehail_fee`) contains empty value.

When loading the csv dataset, `arrow` tries to guess the type of each column when it opens the first file it finds. At that point it assumes that the 14th columns is of type `pyarrow.null()`. When it finds a file that contains a non-empty value for that column it throws an error.

> If I define the schema, will the error be solved? Will it understand, that it should treat "0" as a string?

That should work (but I think it should be a `pyarrow.float()` not a `pyarrow.string()`).